# How to call a method in component for every iteration in *ngFor in angular2?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I want to call a method for every iteration of *ngFor and pass the iterated variable in the method.

for eg.

```
<li *ngFor="let element of componentModel | keys">{{element.key}}--{{element.value}}</li>
```

then I have this method in component as:

```
loadProperty(element:any){
   console.log(element.key);
   console.log(element.value);
}
```

I want this function to get called for every iteration and pass every value of iterated variable.

any inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for this.

```
<li *ngFor="let element of componentModel | keys">
      {{element.key}}--{{element.value}}
      {{ loadProperty(element) }}
    </li>
```

Comment: Tried this. its working but it calling multiple times. I want to call this method only once for every iteration. @NeerPriv

Comment: I dont why. You can call function in a span tag to call one time eg. 

<span *ngIf="element.IsCalled">{{ loadProperty(element) }}</span>

Comment: I am having same issue, Getting called multiple times

Comment: A big reason to want it is when the special computed value is needed in multiple places and so you want to only calculate it once for each loop iteration rather than over and over via individual function calls.